# Исключение java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно использовать исключение `java.util.InputMismatchException`?
вот так ругается на строчку `InputMismatchException`

```
try
    {
        numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
catch(java.util.InputMismatchException){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неверный синтаксис блока catch, т.к. отсутствует имя переменной, представляющей параметр блока.

```
try {

} catch (ExceptionType name) {

} catch (ExceptionType name) {

}
```